# Error in Azure Function Xunit Mock test : Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times

Tags: c#, azure-functions, moq, xunit

I created a azure function with the time trigger code below. Im very new to azure function and xunit. I created both with help of some blogs. I wrote a simple unit test using Xunit in C#. but it returns an error. I tried to solve the issue and not work for me.. Please help me

```
public class DeleteJob
{
    private readonly IStore _store;

    public DeleteJob(IStore store, ILogger<DeleteJob> log)
    {
        _store = store;
        _log = log;
    }

    [Function("DeleteJob")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = false)] MyInfo myTimer)
    {
        
        var canceltoken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8));
        var deleteDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-6);
        try
        {
            await DeleteBlobMetadata(deleteDate, canceltoken.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            _log.LogInformation("Function ran out of time");
        }
       
    }

    private async Task DeleteBlobMetadata(DateTime deleteDate, CancellationToken canceltoken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
            var BlobUrls = await _store.GetBlobBeforeDate(Constants.ContainerName, deleteDate);
            foreach (var blobName in BlobUrls)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                await _store.DeleteBlobAsync(Constants.ContainerName, blobName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            _log.LogError($"Exception when deleting attachments: \n{e}");
        }
```

**Following is  unittest**

```
public class DeleteTest
{

    private readonly Mock<IStore> _StoreMock;
    private Mock<ILogger<DeleteJob>> _logMock;

    public DeleteTest()
    {
        _StoreMock = new Mock<IStore>();
        _logMock = new Mock<ILogger<DeleteJob>>();
    }
    [Fact]
    public async Task DeleteBlobOlderThan6Months_ShouldDelete()
    {
        SetupDeletionSuccessful(true);
        SetupDeleteBlobSetup();
        var sut = GetSut();
        await sut.Run(myTimer: null);
        _StoreMock.Verify(m => m.GetBlobBeforeDate(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<DateTime>()), Times.Exactly(1));
        _StoreMock.Verify(m => m.DeleteAttachmentAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(1));

    }
    private void SetupDeleteBlobSetup()
    {
        _StoreMock.Setup(m => m.GetBlobBeforeDate(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(new List<string> { "someUrl" });

    }

  private void SetupDeletionSuccessful(bool successfulDeletion)
    {
        _StoreMock.Setup(m => m.DeleteAttachmentAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(successfulDeletion);
    }
```

Error is

```
 Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times:
 m => m.GetBlobBeforeDate(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>())
```

Comment: Maybe because your code is `_store.GetBlobBeforeDate(Constants.ContainerName, canceltoken)` but your setup is `m.GetBlobBeforeDate(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<DateTime>())` - the code is talking a cancellation token, but you're checking if it received a DateTime?

Comment: yes. you are right . but that was a mistake in my code.. but i changed it and rerun it.. still same error

Answer (score 0):

The error message is perfectly right. In your test the `GetBlobBeforeDate()` does not get called:

In your test setup the `GetBlobBeforeDate` method to return an empty list:

```cs
 _StoreMock.Setup(m => m.GetBlobBeforeDate(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new List<string>());
```

This means in you function there will be no blob url to delete. Because in your function you delete all `blobUrl`s that have been returned by  `GetBlobBeforeDate`. No items => nothing to delete.

If you want your test to verify that `DeleteAttachmentAsync` gets called exactly once you need a new setup. For example:

```cs
 _StoreMock.Setup(m => m.GetBlobBeforeDate(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new List<string> { "someUrl" });
```

Edit:

On more thing, this time in your code you call:

```cs
await _store.DeleteBlobAsync(Constants.AttachmentContainerName, blobName);
```

But what should be the corresponding Mock setup is:

```
_StoreMock.Setup(m => m.DeleteAttachmentAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(successfulDeletion);
```

As you can see you are comparing apples to oranges. The error is still right: `DeleteAttachmentsAsync` never gets called.

Also in your code you use both `Constants.ContainerName` nad `Constants.AttachmentContainerName` which also seems wrong.

I suggest to setup your Mocks a little bit more explicit and include the corresponding container name. For example:

```
_StoreMock.Setup(m => m.GetBlobBeforeDate(Constants.ContainerName, It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(new List<string> { "someUrl" });
```

This way the mock will also verify that the method has been called with the expected `containerName` parameter value.

Comment: thank you for your help. I changed my code based on your answer and updated in question. but still not working.Maybe my understanding is wrong.. could you please help me

Comment: You mean the order of execution is wrong?